# Laravel 4 check if current path in array do somthing

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to add banner on all the pages except the home page

I try this

```
@if(Request::path() !== array('/', 'home'))
    <div class="bannerImage">{{ HTML::image('images/fullimage3.jpg') }}</div>
@endif
```

and this

```
@if(Request::path() !== '/' or 'home')
        <div class="bannerImage">{{ HTML::image('images/fullimage3.jpg') }}</div>
    @endif
```

how can I do this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert in Laravel but if it will be a plain PHP you can use:

```
@if(Request::path() !== '/' or Request::path() !== 'home')
```

or:

```
@if(in_array(Request::path(), array('/','home'))
```

Comment: did not work, by the way this works `@if(Request::path() !== '/')` but how to put home to it

Comment: OFC you  home  is view name in routes.php? If yes  this bellow or /home should works. IF home is only your url address I think you should use: Route::get() !== '/home'.

Comment: Yes home is in the Route `Route::get('home', 'PagesController@home');`

Comment: thanks I got it the only thing I changed here is `OR` to `AND`
this worked `@if(Request::path() !== '/' AND Request::path() !== 'home')`